# Parse this data format

Tags: java, string

Is there a simpler way, other than String matching, to parse the below string? :

```
com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@719c9e23
    [name=Sprint 1,
     closed=true,
     startDate=2013-04-10T17:58:49.228-07:00,
     endDate=2013-04-24T17:58:49.228-07:00,
     completeDate=2013-04-16T14:42:09.504-07:00,id=10]
```

I am interested in getting the `name`,`closed` and other such values.

(This string is an element of a JSONArray, type `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray`, that I'm getting from JIRA.)

Comment: That doesn't look like valid json.

Comment: It isn't. But that is what I get from JIRA.

Comment: What do you mean by string matching? Regex?

Comment: No there isn't.  This is not a standard serialization form.  It's probably meant for ease of debugging.

Comment: the [] part splits on comma and =, so why not string matching?

Comment: @Paul I wanted to avoid it because thats additional work and the code becomes clunky. For now, I'm tokenizing on ',', then splitting on '=' and storing in a map for easy access.

Comment: Instead of parsing, why don't you call the methods in `JSONArray` to get those values? - http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: Pseudocode:  input.findSubstring(start='[',end=']'). split(',').forEach(pairString){ output(key,value) = pairString.split('='); }

Comment: @Augusto There are no useful methods, except the likes of `get(index)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I did it, that is readable and does not involve regex.

```
String keyValue = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.lastIndexOf("]"));
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(keyValue, ",");
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String entString = tok.nextToken();
    map.put(entString.split("=")[0], entString.split("=")[1]);
}
```

From this point, I get values I need by doing

```
map.get("name")
```

Comment: Good solution, definitely readable why not post this in the first place

Comment: I hadn't actually coded this when I asked the question, then there was a weekend in between :) Also, I was secretly hoping for someone to give me a more concise solution.

Comment: Technically mine is more concise

Comment: Brief, yes. Comprehensive, No. Well at least not for someone who is not well versed with regex.

Comment: Which anyone who considers them self a programmer should be

Answer (score 1):

So this may not be valid JSON but if the form will be the same every time (in terms of no extra levels of nesting) it should be parsable by a regex.

First capture the array using this regex `\[(.*)\]`, the group in the middle will be the data. Then split that data on `,`. Now you have an array where each entry can easily be parsed by a regex of your choosing, unless the entries follow some sort of form that you haven't told us, or I'm not catching, each entry will need it's own specific regex which should be relatively easy to write.

In addition I wasn't sure if the part at the begining

> com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@719c9e23

was important data but that can also be parsed by another regex

> **Solution 2**

So another solution converts the string to valid JSON using 2 regex operations.

First  `String result = searchText.replaceAll("(.|\\n)*(\\[(.|\\n)*\\])", "$1");'\`

This basically just removes that big string from the front.

Next

`result = searchText.replaceAll("(\\w*)=([^,\\]]*)", "\"$1\" : \"$2\"");`

This regex just fixes up the array to make it a valid JSON array, you can now use your JSON parser on the string. As for not using regexes in your solution I say **why not**, a regex is one of the most expressive tools in programming some people over use them but this is a perfect case to use one

Comment: regex make the code clunky and hard to maintain! The easy workaround I have for now is to tokenizing on ',', then splitting on '='

Comment: @VaishakSuresh after looking at it a little longer I can see that once you have the entries in an array you can just use the same regex on all of them to delete the part that isn't data, would your ideal solution be to make it into a valid JSON array

Comment: Regex is harder to maintain than manual String splitting? That's a first :)

Comment: @dkateros have to agree with you here, in general anything involving parsing badly formatted strings is tough to maintain

Comment: @dkateros Regex may be better than string splitting in most situations, but it is clunky in this case! I know for a fact that the separators are ',' and '=', I can easily ignore the '[' and ']'. Why then should I not use `StringTokenizer` and all the good things it offers?

Comment: @VaishakSuresh then what is the problem

Comment: @aaronman The problem, as I have mentioned in the question, is that I want to know if there is a simpler approach than pattern/string matching.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh I think you are the only person who thinks that pattern matching isn't simple, another possible solution could be to make it valid json (shouldn't be too hard) then use your json parser

Comment: @aaronman I did not say pattern matching is complex, I said it affects readability of the code and extensibility hard. I am asking if there are any 'simpler' approaches.
Converting it into JSON might be useful.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh I could post another solution converting it too JSON but the fact is that would also use a regex I'm not sure why you are so opposed to them

Comment: @VaishakSuresh I really can't think of a simpler solution than this if your going to reject it please explain why to me

Comment: @aaronman I have already upvoted the answer! I am still waiting for a while before accepting the answer :)

Comment: @VaishakSuresh no problem, you should really get used to using regexes they are a very powerful tool

Comment: @aaronman - There are definitely situations where using a regex makes code less maintanable.  This is because they are cryptic and difficult to read.  When a new developer stumbles across a regex that looks like this: `(.|\\n)*(\\[(.|\\n)*\\]` he has to sit there and analyze it just to understand what it does (that's just a simple example).  This is generally not the case with more expressive string manipulation.  That said, there is definitely a time and a place for using a regex.

Comment: @jahroy I have a feeling we're not going to agree on this one, unless using a regex is less efficient I think they are great to read

Comment: @aaronman - Well, for one thing a regex is going to be **less** efficient in almost every situation.  A lot of people confuse "_less lines of code_" with "_easy to read_" which I think is a **huge** misconception.  Don't get me wrong, I am a huge fan of regular expressions.  But... I cringe when people try to do too much with them (rather than writing readable code).

Comment: @jahroy cmon you really think I am that naive, a pure regex runs in linear time so if the solution isn't better than linear why not use regex

Comment: To make the code more readable. I value readability **way** above speed.

Comment: @jahroy I told you like 5 comments ago we're not going to agree on that point, it's opinion, why bring it up again

Comment: You asked me why I would do something, so I told you.  That's the reason.  If you ask again, I will respond with the same answer (again).

Comment: [More reading](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/regex-vs-indexof-in-java.html)... and [some more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1062599/778118).... and some [more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8157380/778118).

Comment: quote from your own source "Using indexOf is somewhat faster, but more complex to code. You would only optimise this example if you really needed to as even one million searches takes a fraction of a second." I think your treating this argument as if I would advocate using a regex in any situation, you don't need to tell me that `indexOf` will run faster than a regex

Comment: Ok... I don't think we have anything to debate then.  I've said multiple times that I am a huge fan of regexes.  All I ever did was make the simple point that there are times when they're not the best approach.  I _was_ treating the argument as if you would advocate always using a regex, because that's what it _seemed_ like you were saying.  Sorry I tried to play devil's advocate for a split second.

Comment: We all do... Sometimes we even enjoy them when both parties actually agree with each other ;-)  I assure you that I fundamentally agree with you and am **not** questioning your approach.  Sometimes I'm just a hellbent _code readability crusader_! (_That happens when you travel around a lot inheriting other peoples' code_)

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get this String from? This output does look very much like a `toString()` implementation. Do you have a reference to this JSONArray object? If so:

The [API](http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONArray.html) says that the object provides methods such as `getString(int index)`.

Therefore `sprintObject.getString(0)` should return `Sprint 1`

Comment: The entire string is from `JSONArray.get(0)`, so `sprintObject.getString(0)` does not return `Sprint 1`

Comment: Are you sure that `JSONArray.get(0)` does return a String and not an instance of `com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint` that then should provide methods to access these values?

Comment: Verified again. It does return a `String`

Comment: In that case I guess you are best served with one of the regex based approaches

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use a regular expression to match occurrences between '=' and ',', assuming you know properties name, closed etc are always there in that order and that they do not include '=', ',' and ']' in their values.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("=.*?[,\\]]");
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(value);
while(matcher.find()) {
    matches.add(matcher.group(0));
}
```

com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@719c9e23[name=Sprint 1,closed=true,startDate=2013-04-10T17:58:49.228-07:00,endDate=2013-04-24T17:58:49.228-07:00,completeDate=2013-04-16T14:42:09.504-07:00,id=10]

Based on your sample matches will now contain the following strings:

- name=Sprint 1,
- closed=true,
- startDate=2013-04-10T17:58:49.228-07:00,
- endDate=2013-04-24T17:58:49.228-07:00,
- completeDate=2013-04-16T14:42:09.504-07:00,
- id=10]

You can take it from here I guess.

Edit: Regex being a good approach or not, this data format looks a lot like a return value from something like

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + ... ;
}
```

Also, on second thought, if there really isn't another option than to parse this format, I would match explicitly for the properties, e.g. use regex "name=.*?," for name

Comment: Tag the owner, he won't be notified if just write a comment

Comment: Lol this guy makes us do all this work and then accepts his own solution based on opinion

Comment: @aaronman Heh, the content of the original question should have been more of a clue anyway...